# Adding an entry to the hosts file on iPod touch 4G?

Tags: ipod-touch, hosts

Is it possible to add an entry to your /etc/hosts type file (or whatever the equivalent is) on an iPod Touch 4G without jail breaking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no access to system-level files without jailbreaking.

Comment: Going another route now...http://serverfault.com/questions/220974/bind9-dns-ubuntu-names-pingible-on-server-but-not-on-windows-machines